# When you're waiting for something impatiently

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

In my mother language there is a structure using the adverb "impatiently" which is used to show one's enthusiasm to something. E.g. we say:

A wife says her husband in a phone-call:

> - I am waiting for your return impatiently.

A mother writes her son who is living abroad in a letter or during a chat:

> - I am waiting to see you impatiently.

[These sentences are direct translations from my mother language.]

The only English structure which comes to my mind is "looking forward to doing something", but I'm not sure if it indicates exactly the same message in my question. If it does, please let me know and if not I would appreciate it if someone coud tell me what a native speaker would say in such a situation?

Answer (score 2):

I think the word *"eager"* add the required emphasis. For the phrases in the question you could use:

> I am waiting ... with eager anticipation.
>
> I am eagerly waiting for your return.
>
> I am eagerly waiting to see you.
>
> I am waiting eagerly for your return.
>
> I am waiting eagerly to see you.

The word "anxious" can be used, as in *"I am anxiously waiting for ..."* or *"I am waiting anxiously for ..."*. Although this word has overtones of unhappiness or worry in the sense *"I am anxiously waiting for news from the hospital"*.

Some people like to use *"I cannot wait ..."* to express their eagerness or impatience to see some outcome. For example *"I cannot wait to try that new recipe (for some food item)."* Or *"I cannot wait for your return."*